# How to avoid mac in rhel6 changes on every reboot?

Tags: rhel

I  have a NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet which mac address changes eveytime I reboot my box.

```
[root@sun etc]# dmesg |grep eth0
forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: ifname eth0, PHY OUI 0x732 @ 1, addr 66:b6:95:ea:3e:29
udev: renamed network interface eth0 to eth3
udev: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1
```

This time it's `66:b6:95:ea:3e:29`. How to avoid this?

Comment: What's your kernel version?

Comment: LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch

Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer

Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)

Release:        6.0

Codename:       Santiago

Comment: Linux  2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 19 07:05:20 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Linux version 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Dec 19 07:05:20 UTC 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is offtopic for here, but its a known bug for a long time. See [this extensive discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/153727) at Ubuntu's bugtracker.

It also has a fix proposed some 10 years back.

I know its Ubuntu's bugtracker, but the problem is with the linux kernel drivers. The link there will lead you to some work arounds to solve the problem.

Comment: it's a bug! so I wouldn't fix it but just add a pci network, and everything is good.Thanks for your help.

Comment: can anybody tell em why  my this thread voted -1?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but if I were to guess it would be because it is offtopic.

Comment: It's very kind of you.  I should ask it on other forums.